# Convert a VS project to a test project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

Some of my Visual Studio solutions have projects that build a console applications that uses Google Test to unit-test the libraries built by other projects in the solution.

Recently I got to try out the Google Test Adapter provided in Visual Studio on some new code.  I like how Visual Studio's Test Explorer integrates with the testing framework.  Is it possible to convert my home-grown "test" projects to the Google Test Adapter?

My home-grown "test" projects are just console applications linked against a locally-built copy of the Google Test framework.  I add a Post-Build Event to run the application so that the tests are run automatically whenever the test is rebuilt, which happens whenever the library being tested is rebuilt.

My searches failed to turn up instructions for converting the project type.  I compared the property pages for a Google Test Adapter project and one my of "test" projects to see if I just needed to edit some properties.  But the key seems to be that the GTA project has a "Referenced Packages" section (that's not the same as References).

Is there a straightforward way to convert an existing project, or   should I just create a new Google Test Adapter project, add my tests to it, and eliminate the old project?

Comment: You could use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Your C++ code could be edited with [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...). Your tests could be run with `make tests`. For concrete examples, study the source code of [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or of [FLTK](https://fltk.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  My goal is to get my tests integrated into Visual Studio's Test Explorer.  Switching the entire tool chain gets me farther from that goal, not closer.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is:

1. Create a new Google Test Adapter project in the solution.
2. Add the existing test sources into the new project.
3. Adjust the new project's properties as necessary to match the old ones (warning levels, C++ standards level, necessary include paths, and code gen options).
4. Remove the old project.

It would be nice to be able to convert the old project directly, so please add an answer or update this one if you find a better way.free to